# MIPI DSI display panel for coral dev board

Tags: google-coral

Can someone let me know which MIPI DSI panel can be directly connected to the FFC connector on board without using adapter.

What panel did the coral dev team use for validation of mipi dsi port ? Please share product link...

Answer (score 0):

The Dev Board is tested with the Tianma TL060FVMS07-00.

Comment: Can't find this display anywhere. Is there any alternatives i could use ?